# VBA Word - page number of shape element

Tags: vba, ms-word

I can check on which page given range ends like this:

```
Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Range.Information(3) 'wdActiveEndPageNumber = 3
```

This example returns me the last page in the document. I would like to determine on which page is located a specified shape in my shapes collection.

On Microsoft website there is an example of `Shapes.Range`:

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("Oval 4", "Rectangle 5"))
```

but it looks like it isn't a real range I can extract page number from with `Information` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the shapes Anchor property which returns the range that the shape is anchored to. For example:

```
Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).Anchor.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
```